# BASH dirname basename problems with spaces

Tags: bash

Writing a script to optimize my images for the web. Having issues with filenames and directories with spaces in the names.

Heres what I have:

```
read -p "Enter full path from root (/) to your site... example /var/www/public_html: " path1
echo ""
#read -p "Enter in ImageMagick quality (default is 80) if unsure enter 80: " optjpg
#echo ""
#id="$(id -u optiimage)"
cmd="id -u optiimage"
eval $cmd
id=$(eval $cmd)
tmp1="${path1}/shell/optiimage/imagemagick"
tmp2="${path1}/shell/optiimage/imagemagick/jpg"
restore1="${path1}/shell/optiimage/restore"
restore2="${path1}/shell/optiimage/restore/imagemagick/jpg"
backup1="${path1}/shell/optiimage/backup"
backup2="${path1}/shell/optiimage/backup/imagemagick/jpg"
log1="${path1}/shell/optiimage/log/imagemagick/"
DATE="$(date +%a-%b-%y-%T)"
# Need user input for www path from root
##
## Make directories
##
############################################################################################################
mkdir -p ${tmp1}
mkdir -p ${tmp2}
mkdir -p ${restore1}
mkdir -p ${restore2}
mkdir -p ${backup1}
mkdir -p ${backup2}
mkdir -p ${log1}
mkdir -p ${path1}/build

    echo "Processing JPG Files"
    find $path1 -iname "*jpg" | \
    #write out script to put on cron for image optimization
while read file;
do
    # If not equal to optimage uid
    # to check username id -u optimage
    if [ -u "${id}" ]; then
        filebase=`basename "$file" .jpg`
        dirbase=`dirname "$file"`
        echo "${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg already optimized" >> ${log1}_optimized_$DATE.log
    else
    #simple log for size of image before optimization
    ls -s $file >> ${log1}_before_$DATE.log
    #Do the following if *.jpg found
        filebase=`basename $file .jpg`
        dirbase=`dirname $file`
        echo "cp -p ${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg ${tmp2}" >> ${path1}/build/backup_jpg.txt
        echo "chown optiimage:www-data ${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/restore_jpg.txt #${restore1}/imagemagick.sh
        echo "cp -p ${filebase}.jpg ${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/restore_jpg.txt #${restore1}/imagemagick.sh
    ##
    ## ImageMagick
    ## Original Command:
    ## convert $file -quality 80 ${filebase}.new.jpg
    ##########################
        echo "convert ${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg -quality 80 ${tmp2}/${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/imagemagick.txt 
        echo "mogrify -strip ${tmp2}/${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/imagemagick.txt
        echo "chown optiimage:www-data ${tmp2}/${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/owner_jpg.txt
        echo "rm ${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg" >> ${path1}/build/remove_jpg.txt
        echo "cp -p ${tmp2}/${filebase}.jpg ${dirbase}/" >> ${path1}/build/migrate_jpg.txt
```

## simple log for size of image after optimization

```
     ls -s $file >> ${log1}_after_$DATE.log
    fi
done
```

I have edited this with suggestions some have given me. It didn't seem to work.
This works fine if I remove directories with spaces in the names otherwise it ends the name at the space and get errors directory doesn't exist.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: [Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting): `basename "$file" .jpeg`, `dirname "$file"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote your `$file` variable in every place where is used:

```
find $path1 -iname "*jpeg" | \
    while read file;
    do
        if [ -u "${id}" ]; then
            filebase=`basename "$file" .jpeg`
            dirbase=`dirname "$file"`
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Ha! noticed forgot a couple

Comment: Works Thanks all just need to quote the whole line of text so it works correctly :) Thanks everyone

Comment: Still an issue :/ 
echo "cp -p "${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg" ${tmp2}" >> ${path1}/build/backup_jpg.txt   still results in cp -p /some dir /somedir but not quotes around directories to copy ... g'rrr

Comment: If you're going to add quotes inside a string, escape them with `\"`, p.e., `echo "cp -p \"${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg\" ${tmp2}"`

Comment: Fixed :    echo "cp -p '${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpg' ${tmp2}" >> ${path1}/build/backup_jpg.txt

Answer (score 8):

1. You need to double-quote variable substitutions. This applies inside command substitutions as well as in the top-level lexical context. The only exception to this is assignment of a string variable from another string variable, e.g. `str2=$str1;`, although other types of variable assignments generally need quoting, such as assigning a string variable from an array slice, even if it only slices one element, e.g. `str="${@:1:1}";`.
2. Although unlikely to be a problem here, the `read` builtin strips leading and trailing whitespace if you provide one or more `NAME`s; you can solve that by not providing any `NAME`s at all, and just letting it store the whole line in the `$REPLY` variable by default.
3. You should always use the `-r` option of the `read` builtin, as that prevents its ill-advised default behavior of doing backslash interpolation/removal on the input data.
4. If you don't need any kind of interpolation in a string literal, prefer the `'...'` syntax to `"..."`, as the former does not do any interpolation.
5. Prefer the `[[ ... ]]` expression evaluation form to the old-style `[ ... ]` form, as the former syntax is slightly more powerful.
6. Prefer the `$(...)` command substitution form to the old-style `` `...` `` form, as the former syntax has more favorable nesting properties (namely, no need to escape the nested command substitution delimiters).

---

```
find "$path1" -iname '*jpeg'| \
    # write out script to put on cron for image optimization
    while read -r; do
        file=$REPLY;
        # If not equal to optimage uid
        # to check username id -u optimage
        if [[ -u "$id" ]]; then
            filebase=$(basename "$file" .jpeg);
            dirbase=$(dirname "$file");
            #MYBASENAME=$(basename "$1")
            echo "${dirbase}/${filebase}.jpeg already optimized" >>"${log1}_optimized_$DATE.log";
        fi;
    done;
;
```

Comment: I did not know about point 2 mentioned above, about `read`. Thanks.

Comment: This works and should get in the habit of "${var}" but the quoting the $file worked :)